# My numeric list return Null instead of zero

Tags: r

I have many lists based on one list of two types. One of these list must return `numeric(0)` if the condition is `FALSE` ,however, it returns `NULL` this `NULL` then is counted in the next step which return error length for me. Please note that, I need `psca2` as a list since I do not know how will my data will be.

Here is my code:

```
type1 <- c(2, 6, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 6, 6,3)
type2 <- c(3, 5, 3, 5, 6, 4, 3, 3, 3, 5)
type <- list(type1, type2)
np <- 10
np2 <- list(1,0)
```

### this works fine:

```
psca <- numeric()
psca <- list()
length(psca) <- 2
for (i in 1:np){
  for(j in 1:2){

    psca[[j]][i] <- ifelse(type[[j]][i] %in% c(1, 2, 43, 44), 0.01, 1)
  }
}
```

### this does not work as expected. It returns `NULL` for the second element which must be `numeric(0)`.

```
psca2 <- numeric()
psca2 <- list()
length(psca2) <- 2
for(j in 1:2){
  if(np2[[j]] > 0 ){
    for (i in 1:np2[[j]]) {
      psca2[[j]][i] <- ifelse(type[[j]][i] %in% c(104, 114, 124, 134, 204, 214, 224, 234), 0.05, 1)
    }
    psca[[j]] <- c(psca[[j]], psca2[[j]])
  }
}
```

The output:

```
> psca
[[1]]
 [1] 0.01 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00

[[2]]
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

> psca2
[[1]]
[1] 1
```

### this must be `numeric(0)`

```
[[2]]
NULL
```

any help please?

Comment: You created `psca2` as a `NULL` `list` of `length` 2.  Then you are using `if` condition  `if(np2[[j]] > 0 )`.  So, the second element is not being evaluated and it will return as NULL

Comment: @akrun thank you so much for your great comment. But how can I fix it. Could you please help me?

Comment: If you start with a `list` of `numeric(0)`, it would return it. i.e. `psca2 <- replicate(2, numeric(0), simplify = FALSE)`.  But, I don't understand the whole exercise to return `numeric(0)`  or otherwise, with the present `list`, you can have an `else` condition to return `numeric(0)`

Comment: I just check how many number are for example `2`. Then count it. in my example it is only `1` number is `2`. Then `np2[[1]] = 1` where in second one there is nothing which then `np2[[2]] = numeric(0)`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Try with the `replicate` way

Comment: then this will update my `psca = c(psca, psca2)`

Comment: Could you please add it as answer if it works.

Comment: I find the `psca` to be the same as from the first loop.  Are u missing something?

Comment: @akrun thanks for your help. But it returns me > psca2
`[[1]]
numeric(0)

[[2]]
numeric(0)`  I use this: `psca2 <- replicate(2, numeric(0), simplify = FALSE)
for(j in 1:2){
  if(np2[[j]] > 0 ){
    for (i in 1:np2[[1]]) {
      psca2[[j]][i] <- ifelse(type[[j]][i] %in% c(104, 114, 124, 134, 204, 214, 224, 234), 0.05, 1)
    }
    psca[[j]] <- c(psca[[j]], psca2[[j]])
  }
} `

Comment: `psca` is the update of the first `psca` that is, if we find the number then we add it to the first one.

Comment: That is strange.  I am getting `psca2#
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
numeric(0)`

Comment: could you please send the whole code as answer so I can copy and see.

Comment: Yes, it works now. I think the format of the code. Could you please upload your answer I would like to accept it.

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer.  I remember that I also changed the 1:np2 to seq_along(np2) which is more generala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we initialize a `NULL` `list` of `length` 2 and there is an `if` condition which evaluates only if the element of 'np2' is greater than 0.  As the second element is 0, it won't do anything on that element resulting in `NULL` from the initial object.  Instead, we could initialize a `list` of `numeric(0)` and then apply the condition

```
psca2 <- replicate(2, numeric(0), simplify = FALSE)
for(j in 1:2){
  if(np2[[j]] > 0 ){
    for (i in seq_along(np2)[[j]]) {
      psca2[[j]][i] <- ifelse(type[[j]][i] %in% 
                      c(104, 114, 124, 134, 204, 214, 224, 234), 0.05, 1)
      print(i)
      }

    psca[[j]] <- c(psca[[j]], psca2[[j]])
  }
} 

psca2
#[[1]]
#[1] 1

#[[2]]
#numeric(0)
```

Comment: Then I can change the length of my list as I want.

Comment: @Alice  Yes, you can change 2 to 'n' in `replicate`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really do not know how to thank you.

Comment: @Alice No problem.  Glad to help you